# In the movie Star Trek: First Contact, could the Borg have been beamed off the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-first-contact

In *Star Trek: First Contact*, once the Enterprise's crew found out that the Borg were on board, could they have beamed the Borg off the Enterprise out into outer space, or do the Borg have the capability to block transporter beams?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - I disagree. This isn't (necessarily) about using it as a weapon. Also, it's specifically about the Borg rather than about more general uses.

Comment: A quick comment not worth an answer is that shields (traditionally) block transporters. Borg have been known to have personal shields, so in principle that's why they didn't try it.

Comment: @Valorum Why else would they beam the Borg off the ship!?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - Back to their own vessel?

Comment: @Valorum I doubt even Picard would do that. If you can beam the Borg off your ship, you send them in empty space as far away as possible ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In [VOY: Dark Frontier](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Frontier_(episode)), the crew stage attempt to beam some Borg off the bridge (in a simulation). This proves impossible because individual Borg are able to inhibit transport.

> **CHAKOTAY:** *Beam them out of here.*
>
> **PARIS:** *I can't get a lock. They've adapted to our transport frequencies.*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *Computer, freeze programme, both holodecks. What happened?*

---

Moving (way) down the canon scale, in [Star Trek: Online - Khitomer Crisis](https://sto.gamepedia.com/Mission:_Khitomer_Crisis/Walkthrough), a crewman is capable of beaming some Borg into the pattern buffer, then rematerialising them next to a hull breach, to be jettisoned into space. This only seems to work because the Borg are seriously malfunctioning.